# transfer dictionary to DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dictionary, how can I transform it into a four column DataFrame? (columns=['country','date','2y','10y']

```
temp
    {'Germany':           date    2y   10y
    0   2004-02-01  2.47  4.22
    1   2004-03-01  2.22  4.05
    2   2004-04-01  2.20  3.96
    ..         ...   ...   ...
    149 2016-07-01 -0.65 -0.13

   [150 rows x 3 columns], 'Japan':           date    2y   10y
    0   2004-02-01  0.07  1.32
    1   2004-03-01  0.05  1.26
    2   2004-04-01  0.10  1.42
    ..         ...   ...   ...
    148 2016-06-01 -0.24 -0.12
    149 2016-07-01 -0.33 -0.25
type(temp)
     dict
```

I've tried pd.DataFrame(temp) and pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp). Both return error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and `rename`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [2,3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2,4,5], 'b': [5,6,8]})
temp = {'x': df1, 'y': df2}

print (temp)

print (pd.concat(temp)
         .reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={'index':'country'}))

  country  a  b
0       x  1  2
1       x  2  3
2       x  3  4
3       y  2  5
4       y  4  6
5       y  5  8
```

Another solution with set index name by [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
print (pd.concat(temp)
         .rename_axis(('country','temp'))
         .reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
         .reset_index())

  country  a  b
0       x  1  2
1       x  2  3
2       x  3  4
3       y  2  5
4       y  4  6
5       y  5  8
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your dictionary has data frame as values. If that is the case, one way to reduce the dictionary to a data frame is to loop through the dictionary, create a new column for each sub dictionary and concatenate them:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
for k, v in temp.items():
    v['country'] = k
    df = pd.concat([df, v])
```

A similar example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [2,3,4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2,4,5], 'b': [5,6,8]})
temp = {'x': df1, 'y': df2}

temp    
#{'x':    a  b
# 0  1  2
# 1  2  3
# 2  3  4, 'y':    a  b
# 0  2  5
# 1  4  6
# 2  5  8}
```

Which gives:

```
df.reset_index()

#   a   b   country
#0  1   2   x
#1  2   3   x
#2  3   4   x
#3  2   5   y
#4  4   6   y
#5  5   8   y
```